# Parse Java Date over Jackson JSON to C#

Tags: java, c#, json, unity-game-engine, jackson

I need to parse a java date from a backend to a c# frontend (Unity) via json using the jackson mapper on the backend side and the unity mapper(JsonUtility) on the frontend.

Now these two mappers don't seem to work together, since the unity mapper always fails to receive the correct date and defaults to the "null date".
My question is, do I need to send the date as long (milliseconds) over the wire?
If so, my jackson mapper would need a custom (de)serializer - is there any performance tradeoff with that?

Edit:

There is not much of code to explain:

Maven dependency backend

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Backend (in my case this is spring boot)

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Date;
@Data
public class Backend{
   private Date aDate;

  public Backend() {
  this.aDate = new Date();
  }
}
```

JSON when calling the REST API

```
{
 "aDate": "2018-05-18T22:35:47.760+0000"       
}
```

Frontend (C# / Unity)

```
    using System;
    [Serializable]
    public class FrontEnd
    {
      public DateTime aDate;
    }

  private IEnumerator AcceptWww(WWW www)
        {
         // call made to Backend REST receiving an Backend object here
         yield return www;
        // trying to parse this to a FrontEnd object
        var dateObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<FrontEnd>(www.text);
       // date will always default to 1970
      dateObject.aDate;
        }
```

Thanks in advance,

Codehai

Comment: You are not new here and should know by now that your code is required to figure out the issue with it.

Comment: Hello Programmer, there is not much code to explain this, but still you are completly right - I updated my question to fit the needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
private Date aDate;
```

would be the answer to transport the date as number of seconds since the epoch over the wire. This can be read by C# DateTime - however I have no idea about accuracy and performance on this method.
On C# to pick up the long you would need include something like this to parse the long into DateTime:

```
public static DateTime LongToDate(long javaTimeStamp)
{
    // Java timestamp is milliseconds past epoch
    var dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(javaTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```